# How do I get data from an NSTableView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

I have an `NSTableView` with two columns and a data source that fills it with data. That part works.

How do I get data `(NSString` format) out of the `NSTableView`? I can get the selected row but `NSTableView` doesn't seem to have methods for accessing data.

Getting the data from my data source seems to return useless data (type id and `NSLog()` and `NSRunAlertPanel()` both claim that the data isn't of the type `NSString`.

What's the easiest way to get data from an `NSTableView`?

**Update:**

Turns out the reason getting data from my data source fails has to do with the returning `NSString` being part of an `NSArray` in the `tableView()` method.

My input file contains lines which I split up for the columns in my table view. The `NSTableView` gets the correct data but when I call the `tableView()` method myself I run into a *EXC_BAD_ACCESS* error which I assume has to do with memory management.

**Another update:**

It wasn't memory management. It was my application's inability to identify the `NSTableColumn` it wanted. I wrote a second method to access data manually which uses an int for the column rather than a `NSTableColumn` and that worked.

Comment: In Soviet Russia (and the rest of the world), `NSTableView` asks data from you!

Comment: Yes, dreamlax, I know that. That's why I said that displaying the data is not a problem.

Comment: The point is, you aren't supposed to access the data from your `NSTableView`. What you need to do is load your file into some sort of abstract data model, and have your tableview-datasource-methods AND the rest of your program access the data from this model.

Comment: I know that. But I don't care where the data comes from. I want the data that is in the NSTableView. I just thought there would be an easier way to get it.

Comment: The data *isn't* in the table view. When the table wants to display a cell, it *asks* the data source what should be displayed there. Once it has actually drawn the text on screen, the table view [barring any optimisations] forgets about the data it just used.

Comment: You might want to look into using bindings: http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSArrayController, http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000080.php. They can drastically simplify MVC relationships.

Comment: You really need to brush up on the MVC pattern. There is a serious design problem in your application if you cannot access the same data that you are using to populate a table view.

Comment: outis: Thanks that looks promising!

dreamlax: The design of the application is fine. The problem was that I couldn't find a pointer to the correct NSTableColumn. I had decided that there must be an easier way until I found it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a violation of the MVC paradigm to be using your table (a View) as a place to store your data (Model).  You should be able to get the value from your data source the same way the table view does; what does your code for `tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:` do to get the data?

If your table is editable, you will get calls from the table view to `tableView:setObjectValue:forTableColumn:row:` to allow you to modify your data source appropriately.

Comment: My data source reads the data from a file. But one of the arguments it takes for giving me data is a NSTableColumn? Which one? Also, the data it gives me appears to be something other than NSString but I don't know why.

Comment: The column has a name and a tag you can check on.  The table shouldn't be giving you any data at all...

Comment: You are all overlooking my first sentence. I got the NSTableView to display data. My problem was getting the datasource to give me the same data it gave to the NSTableView. When I tried it using the tableView method it didn't work and I assumed there would be an easier method. There wasn't.

Comment: It sounds as if your solution is likely a bandaid to a bigger design problem. I strongly recommend posting some relevant code and a few words on your overall design and goal. As an eight-year Cocoa veteran, I can tell you something smells very wrong based on the nature of your questions and the solution you found. Not a sleight, just a "woah, that doesn't sound right." :-)

Comment: Why? I am getting the data from my data source object. How can there be a design problem in a program with two classes (not counting a separate class that acts solely as a delegate for the main window)? The problem was that I didn't realise that I needed to get the NSTableColumn from the control in order to get the same data as the control did. I assume NSTableView uses NSTableColumns rather than ints for columns because the columns can be rearranged.

Comment: @JoshuaNozzi - As a five-year Cocoa veteran, I can tell you I was having similar difficulties just because I have little experience with Cocoa bindings and NSTableViews (my apps tend to either be iOS or not require much in the way of a GUI if they're for OS X.)

+1 to Carl's answer here in explaining how to get edits on an NSTableView.

Comment: It's worth noting, ArtOfWarfare, that there's nothing wrong with mixing NSTableViewDataSource protocol with Bindings - easier this way; more configurable that way; best of both worlds when mixed. Old post, though - 11-year veteran now. :-D